# matlab rank correlation function error

Tags: matlab, correlation

I am simply trying to find the Spearman and Kendall correlation coefficients for two vectors.
I have a data matrix ins size 45x2.

when I run this command:

```
corr(data(:,1),data(:,2))
```

I get this error:

```
"Index exceeds matrix dimensions."
```

I also tried the example in [[link]](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/corr.html) and I get this error:

```
"Indexing cannot yield multiple results."
```

Comment: have you tried  `corrcoef(X,Y)`  ?

Comment: Yes corrcoef works but I am not looking for linear correlation.

Comment: corr has nothing to do with Spearman correlation.  You need to look up the formula for the particular kind of correlation coefficient you want, then write it in MATLAB.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spearman's_rank_correlation_coefficient for instance.  There is one MATLAB function (in the stats toolbox) that will help a great deal: `tiedrank` will compute the rank of the variables in the same way that Spearman wants.

Comment: I am looking for Spearman's rho and Kendall's tau which are supposed to be implemented in Matlab corr(), as the reference says.